# how to adjust the background color to the right height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

I'm working on a PHP website using cakephp and twitter bootstrap.
I'm trying to put a background color on the cell on the right. I want the background color cover all the cell. The height of that cell have to be the same as the left part (`col-xs-4`). Right now, I have the background color how cover only the content of the `col-xs-7` cell.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <?php echo $this->Html->image("/img/internet_background_green.png", 
                                              array("class"=>"imgResponsive"));?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 paddingTop20px" >
                <?php echo $this->Html->image("/img/internet_background_green.png",
                                              array("class"=>"imgResponsive"));?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 bgcLightGray marginLeft20px">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image("/img/internet.png");?>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS related to that part:

```css
.bgcLightGray {
    background-color: #bdbcbc;
}
.marginLeft20px {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.paddingTop20px {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.row {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**Here's my fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ENy2/1/)

Comment: And anyway `background:#ffffff;` works for everything.

Comment: I actually have a lightgrey background but it does not cover the entire row height.

Comment: Yes either make a fiddle or post a screenshot

Comment: i'll try to do a fiddle. unfortunately, I don't have the reputation level to put an image.

Comment: this is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3ENy2/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as a CSS solution goes, you'd need to specify a specific height for both of the divs.

If you don't want to mess around with getting the CSS to cooperate, you could use javascript.

```
$('1stDiv').height($('2ndDiv').height());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3ENy2/2/

Comment: It should.  Assign an id to each of your images and set the width and height like I did in my answer.